# phonegap app splashscreen issue?

Tags: cordova

my phonegap app seems to display the wrong splashscreen on android.

When I test the app on my phone, it only displays the 'ldpi' splashscreen, which has to be stretched to fit the screen and therefore is very blurry. If I remove the 'ldpi' call it doesn't display a splash screen at all.

I know my android is capable of diplaying higher res images as I can simply use the default splash screen which appears at higher res.

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

config looks like:

```
<gap:splash src="images/splash-200x320.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-320x480.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-480x800.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-720x1280.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-250x250.png"  gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-320x480.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-640x960.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash-480x800.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
```

what's going on?